# Create thumbnail after upload of any file extension

Tags: file, download

I want to upload a file with any extensions and then from that extension I need to create the thumbnail image for that particular image.
For example, if I upload .pdf file then the thumbnail image should be 'pdf.jpg', so as if .docx file then should be 'word.jpg' and if .zip file then name should be 'zip.jpg'.

I have tried to do this but no luck, file is uploaded but thumbnails is not.

Is there any codes which can do this, I mean to upload any extension and from that extension to create the thumbnail image also?
If any one has idea please share.  :)